# Ember + Sails + Websockets user authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, ember.js, express, sails.js

I use [Ember Sails adapter](https://github.com/bmac/ember-data-sails-adapter) to load my Ember models via websockets. This all works great.

Now I've never actually used user authentication with Ember before, and I'm kinda struggling.
Using the [Sails Auth Generator](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) I created the backend authentication.

When I register a user and login the backend succesfully remembers which user is logged in (due the cookie created).

I have a small game with a few models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    cards: DS.hasMany('card')
});

App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    gameStatus: DS.attr(),
    cards: DS.hasMany('card')
});

App.Card = DS.Model.extend({
    clientSeed: DS.attr(),
    game: DS.belongsTo('game'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

How can I make sure I connect my backend user with Ember? Preferably using websockets (socket.io).

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is a common (and slightly tricky) problem in Ember. You should (to some extent) replicate the Sails authentication system on the client side, in Ember.

One approach: use a singleton authentication manager that checks for the cookie. Add code  right after creating your application, or using an [Ember initializer](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_initializers).